# Why is this keyframe animation not applied when using styled-jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, css-animations, styled-jsx

I tried adding the `animation` on a separate line without any condition, but than the transition is not applied. I also tried backticks instead of double quotes for the `animation` property without success.
How to have the both the animation applied when clicked is `false` and play the transition for the radius when clicked is `true`?

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <svg onClick={() => setClicked((c) => !c)}>
            <circle cx="50%" cy="40%" stroke="black" strokeWidth={2} fill="gray" />
        </svg>
      </main>

      <style jsx>{`
        svg {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }

        circle {
          r: ${clicked ? "10%" : "5%"};
          animation: ${clicked ? "none" : "bounce 2s infinite"};
          transition: r 0.8s ease-in-out;
        }

        @keyframes bounce {
          0% {
            r: 5%;
          }
          50% {
            r: 6%;
          }
          100% {
            r: 5%;
          }
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how styled-jsx applies their css rules.
each `<style jsx>` tag will be transpiled by babel into a piece of js code that will generate and keep track of an actual `<style type="txt/css"/>` tag in the html.

That tag will contain a unique ID, if you inspect that tag it will look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css" data-styled-jsx="">
      svg.jsx-1097321267 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      circle.jsx-1097321267 {
        r: 5%;
        -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
        animation: bounce 2s infinite;
        -webkit-transition: r 0.8s ease-in-out;
        transition: r 0.8s ease-in-out;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes bounce-jsx-1097321267 {
        0% {
          r: 5%;
        }
        50% {
          r: 6%;
        }
        100% {
          r: 5%;
        }
      }
      @keyframes bounce-jsx-1097321267 {
        0% {
          r: 5%;
        }
        50% {
          r: 6%;
        }
        100% {
          r: 5%;
        }
      }
    </style>
```

Notice how the animation is also generated with the same ID.
`bounce-jsx-1097321267`.
**Any static references/classes in the styles-jsx tag also get this id.
This is all done through babel at compile time.**
The resulting js code will do all that referencing for you.

A problem arises when a assigning the css code dynamically.
It seems, that the `${clicked ? "none" : "bounce 2s infinite"};` rule fails to add the generated id to `bounce` animation name.
This might be by design or might be a bug, or simply a limitation in styled-jsx. IDK.

You have a couple of options to work around this,
probably the easiest way is the make the css style static, and add a class when new styling should be applied.

IE

```
 circle {
          r: 5%;
          animation: bounce 2s infinite;
          transition: r 0.8s ease-in-out;
        }

        .is-clicked {
          animation: none;
          r: 10%;
        }
```

and applying a class to circle like
`className={clicked && "is-clicked"}`
, that way the animation name will be contain an id, and any rule using that animation will also receive the same id.

[code sandbox for reference](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-jsx-example-forked-0t2h7?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! However in the example you provided in codesandbox the transition property is still not applied when toggling the classes. (third circle). What I'd like to achive is to play the bounce animation when the circle is small and when clicked _continously_ expand the radius to 10% (transition) and stop the animation. Can you help with that? Thanks

Comment: I would probably do that entirely with classes and transitions. I've updated the code sandbox.  it's kind of finicky to continue from a certain animation state into the transition.  setting animation 'none' only complicates it further.  you can toggle a class based on a timer to achieve the same and it will less jarring when clicking the element.